# How do I scale down integers from multiple values in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a function that will operate on multiple dictionary values at once.

Specifically, I want to take the all the values of selected_keys, divide them by 1 million, and round to two decimal places. Something like this:

```
def scale_down_movie(movie):
    selected_keys = movie['budget'], movie['budget_2013$'], movie['domgross'], movie['domgross_2013$'], movie['intgross'], movie['intgross_2013$']
    for value in selected_keys: 
        round(value/1000000, 2)   
    return movie
```

scale_down_movie(movies[0]) is currently outputting:

```
{'budget': 13000000,
 'domgross': 25682380.0,
 'intgross': 42195766.0,
 'budget_2013$': 13000000,
 'domgross_2013$': 25682380.0,
 'intgross_2013$': 42195766.0
}
```

desired output:

```
{'budget': 13.00,
 'domgross': 25.68,
 'intgross': 42.19,
 'budget_2013$': 13.00,
 'domgross_2013$': 25.68,
 'intgross_2013$': 42.19
}
```

Thank you.

UPDATE:

Used this code:

```
def scale_down_movie(movie):
    selected_keys = ('domgross_2013$', 'budget', 'budget_2013$', 'domgross', 'domgross_2013$', 'intgross', 'intgross_2013$')
    for key in selected_keys:
        movie[key] = round(movie[key]/1000000, 2)  
    return movie
```

Getting unexpected results.

Expected output:

scale_down_movie(parsed_movies[9])

```
{'binary': 'FAIL',
'budget': 130.0,
'budget_2013$': 130.0,
'clean_test': 'notalk',
'code': '2013FAIL',
'decade code': 1.0,
'domgross': 60.52,
'domgross_2013$': 60.52,
'imdb': 'tt1815862',
'intgross': 244.37,
'intgross_2013$': 244.37,
'period code': 1.0,
'test': 'notalk',
'title': 'After Earth',
'year': 2013}
```

Actual output:

```
{'year': 2013,
 'imdb': 'tt1815862',
 'title': 'After Earth',
 'test': 'notalk',
 'clean_test': 'notalk',
 'binary': 'FAIL',
 'budget': 0.0,
 'domgross': 0.0,
 'intgross': 0.0,
 'code': '2013FAIL',
 'budget_2013$': 0.0,
 'domgross_2013$': 0.0,
 'intgross_2013$': 0.0,
 'period code': 1.0,
 'decade code': 1.0}
```

SOLUTION:

```
def scale_down_movie(movie):
    scaled_movie = movie.copy()
    selected_keys = ('domgross_2013$', 'budget', 'budget_2013$', 'domgross', 'domgross_2013$', 'intgross', 'intgross_2013$')
    for key in selected_keys: 
        scaled_movie[key] = round(scaled_movie[key]/1000000, 2)   
    return scaled_movie
```

WHAT WENT WRONG:
Every time you push run, it divides by a million again, so it quickly approaches 0.

HOW TO FIX IT:
Use .copy() so that you're not changing the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like:

```
def scale_down_movie(movie):
selected_keys = ('domgross_2013$', 'budget', 'budget_2013$', 'domgross', 'domgross_2013$', 'intgross', 'intgross_2013$')
for key in selected_keys: 
    movie[key] = round(movie[key]/1000000, 2)   
return movie
```

However this may not return the values you're expecting as you are doing integer division. If you replace `movie[key]/1000000` with `movie[key]/float(1000000)` it should work as expected.

Comment: Hi thank you, I used this code -- very intuitive and similar to my attempt. However I'm getting some odd results.

Comment: What do you define as odd results?

Comment: That will be due to how you're doing division, will update answer.

Comment: nvm! it was because i was rerunning kernel so it divided by a million over and over again. it's fine!

Comment: would be curious what other division method is too, but no worries, your code was spot-on

Comment: I just re-ran it locally looking at the values and I was getting lots of 0.0 too. When I added `float(...)` in it fixed it for me..? Glad it's fixed now anyway :)

Comment: thx ya i fixed by adding a .copy() -- will update question to show final code :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need a new dictionary

```
def scale_down_movie(movie):
    selected_keys = {'domgross_2013$', 'budget', 
'budget_2013$', movie'domgross', 'domgross_2013$', 
'intgross', 'intgross_2013$'}

    return { k: v/1000000., 2)  for k, v in selected_keys.items if k in selected_keys}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the wrong value:

```
def scale_down_movie(movie):
    selected_keys = movie['domgross_2013$'], movie['budget'], 
movie['budget_2013$'], movie['domgross'], movie['domgross_2013$'], 
movie['intgross'], movie['intgross_2013$']
    for value in selected_keys: 
        round(value/1000000, 2)   
    return selected_keys
```

Comment: I think doing this would miss returning all the keys that are also in `movie` but are not 'selected'

Comment: yes Jamie (there are many more keys I didn't list here for brevity's sake)